# How to atomically increment DynamoDB numeric attribute with upper limit and reset?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to use DynamoDB to perform an atomic update on a numeric attribute in such a way that the value will reset back to some predefined value when it reaches some limit e.g. some kind of modulo operation?

For example, if my initial starting value is 1 and the upper limit is 3, the value would increment by 1 on each update but when an increment is performed and the value is currently 3, then the new value would reset back to one.

Would it be possible to do this atomically with some sort of condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no intrinsic way to do this in DynamoDB.

I'd consider simply treating it as a counter and do the modulo arithmetic client-side.

Answer (score 1):

jarmod's answer is indeed the best one when what you need is just modulo. But in other use cases you may need more elaborate logic which must happen at write time and there might be no way to delay it to read time.

One thing you can do in such cases is to use [optimistic locking](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.OptimisticLocking.html): the client reads the old value, calculates the new value using whatever formula it wants, and then writes the new value back; Atomicity is achieved by reading a version number from the item and writing the new value back with the *condition* that the version number hasn't changed (if it changed, you need to repeat the process).

When contention is low, optimistic locking only adds a small cost beyond that of a simple counter increment (it adds a consistent read, which costs less than half than a write). However, if contention is high - i.e., if it is very frequently the case that many clients are trying to update the same value concurrently - the repeated attempts may increase your bill considerably.